# Adding aar library into cn1lib project

Tags: codenameone

We're currently coding a cn1lib for OpenTok framework, but we're stuck at the inclusion of the required libraries.

We need the appcompat-V7-18.0.0.aar and support-v4-18.0.0.jar in order to use the opentok-android-sdk-2.11.0.aar, but we failed at including them.

We get this [log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/9802f03d-0e6d-4df7-af84-87d6f2619eb7-1499948879557-error.txt) from the CN1 build server and use this codenameone_library_appended.properties :

```
codename1.arg.android.proguardKeep=-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }  -keep class android.support.v7.** { *; } -keep public class * extends android.app.Service -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference  -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />     <uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

We think that something is missing in this file, but what ? At this time we're just trying to do the android part, iOS later.

Any idea will be helpful, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are instructions on adding AAR files in the developer guide this isn't the answer you need... Support libraries are a special case. You probably don't need these build hints either.

Check out these [build hints for the Intercom cn1lib](https://github.com/codenameone/IntercomSupport/blob/master/codenameone_library_required.properties):

```
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.arg.ios.pods=Intercom
codename1.arg.ios.pods.platform=8.0
codename1.arg.android.buildToolsVersion=25.0.1
codename1.arg.android.playServicesVersion=9.8.0
codename1.arg.android.supportv4Dep=compile 'com.android.support\:support-v4\:25.+'
```

You can define a different version of play services and build tools, I'm guessing 25 will be new enough to support the requirements of this library.